# Compile error with abstract and does not override abstract method

Tags: java, compiler-errors, syntax-error

When i compile this i get the error  IntSetGenerator is not abstract and does not override abstract method generate_data(int,int) in InstanceGenerator
class IntSetGenerator implements InstanceGenerator. What does this mean? Also what can I do with my code to fix it so that error does not show up.

here is the code for IntSetGenerator

```
 import java.util.*;

class IntSetGenerator implements InstanceGenerator
{
    public Object makeInstance(long seed, long p1, long p2)
    {
        return makeIntSet(seed, p1, p2);
    }

    public long[] makeIntSet(long seed, long size, long max)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int arraysize = Long.valueOf(size).intValue();
        int maxvalue = Long.valueOf(max).intValue();
        long [] iset = new long[arraysize];
        Random randgen = new Random(seed);

        while (count < size)
        {
            iset[count] = (long) randgen.nextInt(maxvalue)+1;
            count++;
        }
        return iset;
    }

    public long[] makeIntSet(long size, long max)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int arraysize = Long.valueOf(size).intValue();
        int maxvalue = Long.valueOf(max).intValue();
        long [] iset = new long[arraysize];
        Random randgen = new Random();

        while (count < size)
        {
            iset[count] = (long) randgen.nextInt(maxvalue)+1;
            count++;
        }
        return iset;
    }   
}
```

Here is the code for InstanceGenerator

```
public interface InstanceGenerator { 

    public int[] generate_data(int size,int maximum);


}
```

Comment: You need to implement the `generate_data` method from `InstanceGenerator` or declare your class `abstract` since you haven't defined a class yet that implements `InstanceGenerator`.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement the generate_data(int value, int maxValue) in the IntSetGenerator class.

Example:

```
public int[] generate_data(int size,int maximum){
    //do something here
}
```

Or mark the IntSetGenerator class "abstract". Like Marc Baumbach said.

Example:
`abstract class IntSetGenerator implements InstanceGenerator{}`